# Highlighting certains words in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, spock

I am writing spock tests in Groovy / Grails in Eclipse. These use key words such as `setup:` `the:` and `when:`.  I'd like to be able to add some syntax highlighting to these words.  Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This issue seems to be related to this [jira](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRECLIPSE-1212), which has not be addressed yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the Spock Eclipse plugin: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/spock-plugin#.Uht-2Lw26KQ  I think it will do what you require.

Answer (score 1):

[XText](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/index.html) looks really cool, with extensive documentation and support. Is it too complex for what you need?

Either that, or if you have knowledge and experience with Eclipse RCP, you could [create your own text editor](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_an_editor_for_my_own_language%3F), and add the project to your IDE.