# Intellisense not working properly for SPOCK framework in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: groovy, eclipse-indigo, spock, geb

On Pageclasses (e.g LogInExample.groovy) user-defined or inbuilt methods or variables are not auto populated due to which it seems difficult to code.
For example when we write Checkbox. after putting this dot inbuilt methods should be auto populated which has not been done. Refer the attached screenshot  for more information.

Intellisense not working properly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441156/highlighting-certains-words-in-eclipse

Answer (score 1):

Intellisense is working fine for me in Keplar 4.3. Perhaps you want to try an upgrade of your IDE.